# Why does assigning a local variable change the behaviour of previous lines of code in a function?

Tags: python

Been doing tests to try to understand what's written in the documentation here.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

I've noticed that, if a function uses a variable that hasn't been defined locally, it will use the variable as set in the parent scope. However, if that function sets that variable later on in the function, it will instead decide that it can't use the variable set in the parent scope and die.

The first function below works, the second function does not.

```
def printthingy():
    print(foo)
    #foo = 'goodbye world'

def printthinghy2():
    print(foo)
    foo = 'goodbye world'

foo = 'hi world'
printthingy()
printthinghy2()
```

I expect the functions to behave consistently in terms of being able to find foo for printing. Instead, the first function works and the second function gives a "local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment" error.

Answer (score 1):

Read about local and global variable. In Python every variable that is assigned within a function is considered local by default, global otherwise. So first works since `foo` is considered global and second crashes since it is considered local but not assigned yet when it is first accessed.

Comment: Why does it become considered local because it is assigned later? Intuition is that it only becomes local as it gets assigned. Otherwise it causes cases such as the example code where adding a line later in the function assigning a variable inexplicably breaks earlier lines.

Comment: Well @SirTophattingson, python, here, does not follow intuition.

Comment: It is perfectly explicable: I gave you the explanation. There are rules and you just have to follow them.

Comment: In your second example the compiler (yes, Python has a compiler) defines the variable as local and when you run the program it tries to print this still undefined local variable.